# function does not work via post request (node js)

Tags: javascript

for understanding, here is my test work on github https://github.com/ALLADMINdotRU/PHONE.git

There is an HTML form with a save button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Configuring a MySQL database connection</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Connect config</h1>
     <form action="postMySQLconfigSave" method="POST">
        <label>IP server address</label>
        <input IPaddressServerMySQL="IPaddressServerMySQL" /><br><br>
        <label>Login</label>
        <input LoginMySQL="LoginMySQL" /><br><br>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input PasswordMySQL="PasswordMySQL" /><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
     </form>
     <a href="/users">Back to user list</a>
</body>
<html>
```

when you click on the save button, the postMySQLconfigSave function should be executed

```
const fs = require("fs");      

exports.postMySQLconfigSave = function(request, response){
    fs.writeFileSync("./config/MySQLconfig.txt", "Hello world") ;      //

    console.log("Here was the code");
    response.send("About the site");
};
```

but it doesn't work, why?
Although if you just write the route to it in the address bar, then everything is OK

routes

```
const express = require("express");
const сontrollerMySQL = require("../../controllers/MySQL/controllerMySQL.js");
const сontrollerMySQLconfig = require("../../controllers/MySQL/controllerMySQLconfig.js");
const routerMySQL = express.Router(); // определяем Router

// определяем маршруты и их обработчики внутри роутера homeRouter
//routerMySQL.get("/create", сontrollerMySQL.about);
//routerMySQL.get("/config", сontrollerMySQL.index);
routerMySQL.get("/error",                           сontrollerMySQL.error);
routerMySQL.get("/connect",                         сontrollerMySQL.connect);
routerMySQL.get("/test",                            сontrollerMySQL.test);

routerMySQL.get("/config",                          сontrollerMySQLconfig.config);
routerMySQL.get("/postMySQLconfigSave",             сontrollerMySQLconfig.postMySQLconfigSave);

module.exports = routerMySQL;  //делаем доступным наш результат снаружи
```

Comment: Your `<form>` says the method is `POST`, but your route is using `get`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yours form have a POST method, this method doesn't exist in action.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong here is not giving accurate path for the `action`. You can verify this by opening chrome-dev-tools and going in network tab. Turn on the preserve log checkbox to make sure the redirection doesn't cause your requests to be cleared. You should update your code like so `action="/postMySQLconfigSave"`.

Comment: i tried setting the following values

`<form action="postMySQLconfigSave" method="POST">
<form action="/postMySQLconfigSave" method="POST">
<form action="/mysql/postMySQLconfigSave" method="POST">`
but nothing worked

After I tried to change to GET and it worked. Why is not clear.

`<form action="postMySQLconfigSave" method="GET">`

Answer (score 0):

error found

in routes i used GET call
`routerMySQL.get("/postMySQLconfigSave",             сontrollerMySQLconfig.postMySQLconfigSave);`

but it was natural to use POST
`routerMySQL.post("/postMySQLconfigSave",             сontrollerMySQLconfig.postMySQLconfigSave);`